# How to install Postgres server-side (backend) header files for an already-installed version of Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I recently upgraded to Postgres 9.5 simply by installing from Ubuntu package repos. Everything went smoothly in the upgrade and I regularly use Postgres and all my previous data.

However, I am also working on some C language extensions and need to import the backend header "postgres.h" -- which is not found in the Postgres include dir.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/install-procedure.html) (search for 'server header files' and read the note) suggests that there should be private subdirectories under the base include directory and that server-side headers will be installed there, but this is not the case for me.

Using `find` to search the entire machine for "postgres.h" reveals that the only copy is in a separate directory where I downloaded an older version of the Postgres source just for reading and searching code -- not at all for supporting an installation.

I want to avoid rebuilding or reinstalling Postgres at all costs, as everything is working fine. I just need to make the headers available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Ubuntu and Debian, the server header files are in a separate server-dev package you mudt install, e.g. `postgresql-server-dev-9.5`.

BTW I strongly advise you to compile your extensions using [pgxs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html).