# How to install pgxn with correct PostgreSQL version?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

On `sudo -H  pgxn install semver`, ERROR about wrong PostgreSQL version (it is v10 not v12),

```
INFO: best version: semver 0.20.3
INFO: saving /tmp/tmpba6hta5a/semver-0.20.3.zip
INFO: unpacking: /tmp/tmpba6hta5a/semver-0.20.3.zip
INFO: building extension
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith... src/semver.c: In function ‘tail_cmp’:
src/semver.c:440:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   char *dot = ".";
   ^
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -...
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//doc/semver.mmd '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-12/extension/'

INFO: installing extension
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-12/extension'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//semver.control '/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//sql/semver--0.20.0.sql ...
```

I try also to fix "postgresql headers", by [this clue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38166638/287948) using `sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-10`, but no effect.

I was using the [pgxn.org](https://pgxn.org/) extensions, that has no obvious "installation Guide" on its home. Seems that the Guide is [pgxn.github.io/pgxnclient](https://pgxn.github.io/pgxnclient/), but it say nothing about change PostgreSQL configs (but [Pg Guide about extend-pgxs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-pgxs.html) perhaps say something).

---

More details on [json_fdw/issues](https://github.com/nkhorman/json_fdw/issues/10) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60598749/287948).

---

### ENV details

- on `psql "postgres://postgres:passwd@localhost/myBase" -c "select version()"` = PostgreSQL 10.12
- old server UBUNTU 16 LTS
- `psql --version` = 12.2 (but SQL is 10.12!)
- `pgxn` installed by `sudo easy_install pgxnclient`.
  redo by `sudo -H pip install --upgrade pgxnclient`
    `pgxn --version` = pgxnclient 1.3
- for `json_fdw` package prepared, before *pgxn install*, with sucess `sudo apt install zlib1g-dev libyajl-dev`.

Seems the real problem is a PostgreSQL version confusion: the two exists, `ls /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension` and `ls /usr/share/postgresql/12/extension`

Comment: how did you fix this?

Comment: Hi @lightweight, sorry, abandoned... `pgxn` seems not "super reliable", it depends on some support, that I not have for little projects.

Answer (score 1):

The installation worked fine, the warning is about a code bug in semver.

The extension is built and installed with the PostgreSQL v12 installation on your machine, because the `pg_config` found on the `PATH` is the one from v12. If you want to build and install the extension with v10, make sure the `pg_config` from v10 is first 
on the `PATH`.